# My electrical stack exchange account was banned from asking more questions. What should I do?

Tags: discussion

I add a comment for a person on my question. I was rude as he was with me. Okay I AM SORRY, but how can I get my account back in electrical stackexchange?

Comment: Talk to a moderator in the chat room, odds are if you were banned from being rude you'll be given a cool down time. It doesn't look like your account has been banned. SE's policy is be nice, those who aren't nice go to the penalty box: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Answer (score 4):

You have been banned from asking questions due to an excessive number of low-quality questions. Deleted questions count in this total as well. See the [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) for further information.

Comment: So what should I do. Wait for 6 months?

Comment: @droidnation You can fix your questions. See details on  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: I deleted the question. SO I should undelete it again and edit it right ?

Comment: Correct - deleted and <=0 score questions count against you. I cannot lift the ban, it is something the system evaluates automatically.

Comment: I don't understand why deleted questions count. They aren't on the site anymore, are they? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @DanielTork It's that the user put questions up that needed to be deleted, and the deleted questions have a bad score as well. The reasoning is that the majority of questions a user has asked are not useful for the site - the next one is also likely to be poorly received.

Comment: @W5VO Wasn't the rep penalty enough? I understand what you said, but keeping track of deleted questions is a bit overzealous for me, unless low quality posts appear more often than I thought.